# Eclipse Syntax Coloring reset after restart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes

I installed Ubuntu 15 new and I installed eclipse Mars.

Now, I want to have the syntax highlighting exactly like in visual studio, so i downloadet the .epf here http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=23347 and imported it into eclipse. 
Until here, I have no problems, but when I restart eclipse the highlighting will reset after 5 seconds to default.

I don't know why, but when I start eclipse via sudo, I don't have the problem. I have no more ideas...

I saw, that eclipse run this on startup:
http://pastebin.com/6YGVxfhU

I dont know, how i can stop it

Comment: If it works with sudo but not otherwise, check that your workspace is fully writeable by your user account.

Comment: My Workspace is under /home/username and i tryed chmod 777 -R workspace   but nothing helps

Comment: It looks like Oomph restores the setting with the Start Up Tasks, but I didn't find a way to deactivate it

Comment: I have essentially answered the question from your last comment, it is not exactly what you had in your original question, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### To disable all Oomph startup tasks

In preferences, choose *Oomph* | *Setup Tasks*. Then check the *Skip automatic task execution at startup time*.

[image]

### To disable which preferences Oomph tracks

1. In preferences, choose *Oomph* | *Setup Tasks* | *Preference Recorder*.
2. Check the *Record into:* checkbox.
3. In the table uncheck the preferences you don't want synchronized. For your case it is probably the set of `/instance/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/[...]`.
4. (Optional) Click *Open the recorder target file* button and fully edit your preferences.

[image: recorderer]

Comment: I love you, I think It runs

Comment: @DEVV Share the love, please upvote/accept if it worked out, if not give more details.

Comment: First Tip helped, but I wanted to be safe, so I unchecked oll Boxes with "ui" in name in the called setting menu.

Comment: Great. I think that there is a gap in applying the Eclipse Color Themes that should be made easier and get along with Oomph better. I don't know how active the themes devs are, but perhaps as you are finding the themes useful you could let them know that their Oomph integration could be improved.

Comment: Or instead of adding a massively complex configuration tracking management system (Oomph) they could have added theming capabilities directly into Eclipse like ~10 years ago instead of an external plugin.

Comment: @AdamGent the theming support is in Eclipse for nearly 10 years, but I will grant that Oomph is complicated retro-fit. However, Eclipse Color Themes is a set of addons to add additional colour palettes into Eclipse, using Eclipse's own theming support to render them. It is equivalent to downloading new desktop themes for Windows or other OS.

Comment: @JonahGraham I am not trying to be that contentious but the ability to change font syntax colors adhoc is not really theming. By that measure Emacs has had themes since global font lock mode. Themes are about packaging up the the syntax colors and all the other UI things (or as multiple packages for ui components + syntax). As for configuration Eclipse makes that about opaque as possible (for better or worse). It is like the windows registry but far worse. It is a giant HashMap. I know people hate XML files but I wish Eclipse chose that instead of property files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Oomph to track your syntax, you can import the .epf file into the preference recorder:

1. Open *Window > Preferences* and go to *Oomph | Setup Tasks | Preference Recorder*
2. Make sure *Record into* is selected and whichever profile you want to record to is selected (probably User.) Open the recorder file using the button next to the dropdown.
3. A .setup file will open in the editor. Close the preference window. An Oomph toolbar should have appeared. The third button is *Import Preferences*.
   [Oomph - Import Preferences Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1F95.png)
4. Click it, browse to your .epf file and open it. Move whatever preferences you want to import from *Available Preferences* to *Selected Preferences* and click *OK*.
5. The preferences will be added to the .setup file, under the root node (probably *User*.) Drag them into the *User Preferences* node (the first child node with the folder icon) and delete any existing nodes with conflicting names (it won't combine them.)
6. Save the file.

You should now be able to restart Eclipse and have Oomph load in your correct syntax coloring.

Answer from [this eclipse forum post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1074674/) with a few extra steps I had to do to get it working.